# Can we debug inline javascript through firebug and have break point

Tags: javascript, firebug

We normally debug the javascript files like .js by having breakpoing in firebug , is there any way to debug inline javascript inside the page.

We have lot of inline code in the page itself with  , let me know if there any efficent way of debugging.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use firebug to debug the javascript between your `<script>` tags.

Comment: you are right , we have select script and then the page name , thank you very much , i will mark it as answer.